# Typed serialization library across languages?

Tags: serialization, encoding

Suppose there's a server that processes composed data of unknown type.

With JSON-schema and Protobufs, the developer converts struct/object definitions into schemas and uses the schemas on the server when processing incoming data - the type of composed data needs to be known in advance.

Is there a "dynamic serialization type format" that would do this dynamically, with unknown data, such as:

```
{
  "age" : {
    "_type" : "uint8",
    "_min" : 0,
    "_max" : 100,
    "value" : 15
  }
}
```

The schema information is passed together with the data on ad-hoc basis, as opposed to having to put the proto/json-schema file on the server.

Jackson or Python pickling wouldn't cut it here since those would be confined to e.g. Java or python - the question is whether there's dynamic type serialization format (not at all necessarily JSON) where a library following  such a format is implemented in multiple languages.